# How do I Select "sales count" for each item and show as "popularity" in Select ALL "design" options MySql statement?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: sales and designs

I want to select the designs from the design table and then include the popular designs count from the sales table for each design and then display the design name, attributes and then the popularity count for each design. If no sales for a design we must still show the design, i.e. popularity will be Zero.

Example: Design one, name, attributes: (Popularity count)

This Mysql statement selects all the designs:

```
SELECT * FROM `designs`
WHERE status=1
ORDER BY priority ASC
```

This MySql statement selects the popular designs from sales:

```
SELECT COUNT( `design` ) AS designCount,
designs.id,
designs.title
FROM `sales`
INNER JOIN designs ON sales.design = designs.id
WHERE design != ''
AND paid =1
GROUP BY design
ORDER BY designCount DESC
```

I want to combine the 2 into one statement, where I can retrieve all the design information for the designs available and simply add the popularity of each design to each row result.

My table schema is as follows:

The `designs` table: id, title, designName, description, designVoucher, theme, value, priority, dateUploaded, dateUpdated, status

The `sales` table:id, name, surname, email, tel, design, date_purchase, paid

I have tried something like this but it only returns the total popularity results for each row:

```
SELECT * , (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS popCount
    FROM sales
    INNER JOIN designs ON sales.design = designs.id
    WHERE sales.design = designs.id
    AND paid =1
) AS popularity
FROM `designs`
WHERE status =1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a temporary table containing the `sales` totals (i.e. the "popularity") for each design, then I `JOIN` that to the `designs` table:

```
SELECT * FROM designs d
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT design, COUNT(*) AS popCount
    FROM sales
    WHERE paid = 1
    GROUP BY design
) s
ON d.id = s.design
WHERE d.status = 1
```

Comment: Man that is so simple, I had forgotten about temporary tables, was wrestling with creating aliases but you can't read aliases from a main query in a sub-query.

Comment: Your answer excludes the designs that have no sales!

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works, `LEFT JOIN` will also include the designs which haven't yet sold.

```
SELECT Design.*, COUNT(Sale.id) saleCount 
FROM designs Design LEFT JOIN sales Sale 
    ON Design.id = Sale.design AND Sale.paid = 1
GROUP BY Design.id
ORDER BY Design.priority
```